Массивы, вывести в консоль последний элемент
let morningList = [
  'Встать с кровати',
  'Почистить зубы',
  'Проверить сториз в Инстаграме',
  'Позавтракать'
];

console.log(morningList[0]); // Выведите первый элемент
console.log(); // Выведите последний элемент

Помогите пожалуйста, очевидное решение, но запуталась. В консоль выводится число, а надо слово
let morningList = [
  'Встать с кровати',
  'Почистить зубы',
  'Проверить сториз в Инстаграме',
  'Позавтракать'
];

console.log(morningList[0]); // Выведите первый элемент
console.log(morningList.length - 1); // Выведите последний элемент


https://doka.guide/js/array-at/

morningList.length - 1 - чем вам этот вариант не подходит? только надо вот так: morningList[morningList.length - 1]

Всё теперь подошло, не полностью расписала. Спасибо большое!))

Если сам массив больше не нужен - Первый morningList.shift(), последний morningList.pop().

@ksa, эти методы меняют массив, что может быть не очень хорошо, даже если массив после этого не используется

Давайте продолжим обсуждение в чате.

Не очень давно массивам добавили метод .at(), который может принимать отрицательные значения, в этом случае последний элемент можно получить вызвав .at(-1).
Без использования этого метода, сначала потребуется вычислить индекс последнего элемента. Как правило, он равен length - 1
Затем обратившись по этому индексу получить сам элемент


let morningList = [
  'Встать с кровати',
  'Почистить зубы',
  'Проверить сториз в Инстаграме',
  'Позавтракать'
];

console.log(morningList.at(-1)); 
console.log(morningList[morningList.length-1]); 




Но вы здесь (уже тут) меня удивили – функция at() не должна советоваться от модератора, ибо некоторые пользователи могут сочти это как руководство к действию и писать её в коде, а это в большинстве случаев вызовет ошибку в браузерах. Пожалуйста измените свой ответ

@Bharatha, данный метод уже поддерживается в последних версиях всех основных браузеров. В каких браузерах и когда ты получаешь ошибку?

Это далеко не так! Вы даже не представляете какие трудности испытывают люди на смартфонах, когда начинают использовать крайне глупо такие функции!Посмотрите какие версии iOS поддерживают четвёртый, пятый и шестой iPhone. Они даже не могут обновиться, потому что Apple это не поддерживает.  Пользователи iPhone 7-11 тоже имеют с этим трудности, если их системы не обновлены хотя бы до четырнадцатой версии iOS. Так что вы очень сильно заблуждаетесь!

@Bharatha, в данном случае это не проблема метода ¯\(ツ)/¯ iPhone6 - был выпущен 10 лет назад, если использовать такой подход можно писать, что во всех ответах должно быть предупреждение, что любой код вызывает ошибку в браузере, так как всегда можно откатиться чуть больше времени назад и взять множество малоиспользуемых браузеров. Если нужно поддерживать старые браузеры - достаточно пользоваться полифилами, в этом случае ошибок не будет.

Полифилами никто не пользуется. Большинство разработчиков даже не думают о таких вещах – им это не известно. Если таким людям указать на ошибку, то они даже не будут её исправлять. Вот так же напишут как и вы, что якобы они сами виноваты. ☹️ Вот если бы у вас был iPhone 6, к примеру, а кто-то на stackoverflow использовал новые функции, из-за чего вы не могли бы зайти на эту страницу, то я хотел бы на вас посмотреть.

@Bharatha, у меня есть iPhone6 - и если сайт не работает - я на него не захожу ¯\(ツ)/¯
